# How to add an AD group to use queues in Release Management in VSTS?

Tags: permissions, azure-devops, release-management, ms-release-management

In Visual Studio Team Services I tried to define permissions to allow a certain group permissions to manage release definitions.

I therefore added the Active Directory group to the `Release Administrators` group in the team project. If a user from the specific group logs into Visual Studio Team Services and tries to create a release definition (or does some other managing operation) he receives the following error:

`Access denied. UserX needs Use permissions for queue Default to perform this action. For more information, contact the Team Foundation Server administrator`

It seems like the user generally has permissions to create a release definition, but lacks permission on the release queue. How can I give a certain Active Directory group Use permissions to an agent queue?

If I add the Active Directory group also to the `Project Collection Build Administrators` group on the Default Collection level, managing release definitions work. But this will also give them permissions to build definitions, which they don't require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the AD group to Agent Queue Users group or Agent Queue Administrator group as per your requirement. To do that, go to the Agent Queues tab in the settings at Collection/Account level

[image]